# Check a date (excluding year)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

In SQL Server, how can I check if one calendar date consisting of a day and month is older than another certain date, programmatically?

For example: I need to check if TransactionDate is on or before June 30, in all year.

`TransactionDate <= (June 30)`

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  (e.g.: `SQL Server`, `MySQL`, `Oracle`, etc.)  Date functions are very specific and vary between different engines.

Comment: @Siyual Sorry, I should have mentioned it earlier. I'm using MS SQL Server

Comment: Use a DBMS specific function to extract the month of a date and check for `< 7`. For T-SQL: `DATEPART('m', mydate) < 7`

Comment: Use `Month` function

Comment: @Sami what should I do when the date is June 15?

Comment: @AsifChowdhury the use `Month` and `Day` functions , then check

Comment: For June 15: `WHERE DATEPART('m', mydate) * 100 + DATEPART('d', mydate) <= 615`

Answer (score 3):

Use `DATEPART` like this:

```
 declare @var1 date = '2016-02-07';
 declare @var2 date = '2017-02-06';

 SELECT CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(MM, @var1 ) * 100 + DATEPART(DD, @var1 ) 
    > DATEPART(MM, @var2  ) * 100 + DATEPART(DD, @var2 )   THEN 'YES' 
 ELSE 'NO' END AS LARGERDATE;
```

It compares the dates as two integers in form of MMDD. For example:

`'2016-02-07'  ==> 207, '2017-02-06' ==> 206`

`'2010-10-27'  ==> 1027, '2017-07-29' ==> 729`

Answer (score 1):

Most correct way will be to use <kbd>[DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql)</kbd> function; especially because it is available from all versions of SQL server since 2008, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse too.

You can check using the expression assuming you have the date to be compared against stored in `@yourCheckDate` variable

```
DECLARE @yourCheckDate DATETIME
DECLARE @m INT
DECLARE @d INT
SELECT @yourCheckDate = CAST('2017-6-30 12:15:32' AS DATETIME)
SELECT @m= DATEPART(month, @yourCheckDate)
SELECT @d= DATEPART(day, @yourCheckDate)



-- expression 
select 1 where
      DATEPART(month,@tranDate) < @m 
     OR
     ( DATEPART(month,@tranDate) = @m AND DATEPART(day,@tranDate) <= @d )
```

Comment: `Month` and `Day` functions also available.(2008+)

Comment: This would incorrectly exclude the 31st of January, March and May.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Server 2008 solution which supports any calendar date, derived from  @TheEsisia and @Sami answers

```
WHERE 100*MONTH(TransactionDate) + DAY(TransactionDate) <= 100*MONTH(@checkDate) + DAY(@checkDate)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using SQL server 2008. DATEFROMPARTS function is in play from 2012.

Answer (score -1):

This should work if you want to get all dates from a date to the end of the year. Basically constructing a 'xxxx-12-31' with the input date (example in Oracle).

```
BETWEEN yourDate AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(yourDate, 'YYYY') ||'12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: The question is tagged `SQL Server`, not `Oracle`.

Comment: It was not before. Anyway the same logic works in any DBMS, a quick googling to get the mssql keywords won't hurt.

Comment: Then you should update your answer to use SQL Server syntax.  "Here's a solution using a different language, google around to translate it" is not a valid answer.

Comment: Like I said, I wrote this answer at a time where the mssql tag was not there. I do not know the mssql functions to get the year from a date and am not interested in searching for it (wouldnt be able to test it anyways). Consider my answer as pseudo code if you want.